# How can I manipulate TemporalData?

Tags: version-9, date-and-time, undocumented, time-series

Version 9 introduced [`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TemporalData.html) but, truth be told, the documentation doesn't suggest that one can do much with it. Many of us have probably assumed we'd be better off sticking with the date-value pairs familiar from use in `DateListPlot` and elsewhere.

Are there some (perhaps undocumented) functions I can use to manipulate temporal data after putting it in `TemporalData` form?

Comment: Time series and random processes are some useful applications of TemporalData...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries - indeed, but if you have some actual time series data - say GDP of a country - and you want to do stuff to it like calculate a percentage change or  a moving average, the functions below seem quite useful.

Comment: Seems like _Mathematica_ 10 will have this kind of functionality built in, but under slightly more general names: [`TimeSeriesXxx`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TimeSeriesProcessing.html), being able to operate on vectors, time-value-pair-lists, `TimeSeries`, `EventSeries` and `TemporalData` objects.

Comment: Yes, [TimeSeries](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/time-series/new-time-series-functions.html) functionality is now built into _Mathematica_ 10.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The short answer is, yes! There is a whole undocumented package `` TemporalData` `` containing some useful functions.

> The results below are from my own spelunking. Feel free to add/amend as appropriate.

Let's set up some simple `TemporalData` objects to explore them:

```
fakedata = 
  Transpose@{DatePlus[{2001, 1}, {#, "Month"}] & /@ Range[0, 99], 
    Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]] - 2};
temp = TemporalData[fakedata];
fakedatalater = 
  Transpose@{DatePlus[{2010, 5}, {#, "Month"}] & /@ Range[0, 99], 
    Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]] - 2};
templater = TemporalData[fakedatalater]

DateListPlot[temp["Paths"], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Here are the functions revealed by the command `` ?TemporalData`* ``. Some of them have usage messages (these are given where exist, with all the developer typos) and are all `ReadProtected`.

### Aggregate

> `Aggregate[td,dt,f]` aggregates each path over time intervals of width
>   `dt` using aggregating function `f`, where `dt` can be a number, a date
>   increment such as `"Month"` or a list `{n,t}` where `n` is a number and `t` is
>   a date increment.
>
> `Aggregate[td,dt]` uses `Mean` of the intervals of width
>   `dt` to aggregate.

```
aggd = TemporalData`Aggregate[temp, {3, "Month"}];
DateListPlot[aggd["Paths"], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

You can aggregate several ways. The default is `Mean`, but `Variance`, `StandardDeviation`, `Total` and `Median` are also possible, as are some more obscure aggregation methods like `Quantile[#, 0.95] &`, `Skewness`,`Kurtosis`, `TrimmedMean[#, 0.2] &`, `GeometricMean`, `HarmonicMean`, `ContraharmonicMean` (including things like `ContraharmonicMean[#, 4] &`):

```
aggd = TemporalData`Aggregate[temp, {3, "Month"}, Total];
DateListPlot[aggd["Paths"], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

In fact as far as I can tell, pretty much anything that condenses a vector of numeric values to a single number works, e.g. `Mean[Abs[#]] &`.

**Caveat: aggregating at the `"Month"` frequency might introduce shifts in starting days!**

`TemporalData` assumes that a month is **always** 31 days long (it simply adds 2678400 seconds to the `AbsoluteTime` values at each step):

```
td = TemporalData[{DatePlus[{2001, 1}, # - 1], #} & /@ Range@500];
Differences[TemporalData`Aggregate[td, {1, "Month"}]["Times"][[1]]]/3600/24

(* {31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31} *)
```

which results in accumulating error in days (i.e. next aggregate won't start at the 1st of the month).

### DateSpecification

`DateSpecification` is an internal wrapper for implicit `TemporalData` time specification, not available for direct use. According to the definition of `ExtendTimes`, `TemporalData[...]["UnexpandedRawTimes"]` can return the time for each path in one of the following formats:

1. implicit `{mint, maxt, dt}` in `AbsoluteTime` format
2. a vector of explicit time values, e.g. `{1, 2, 3, ...}`
3. implicit `DateSpecification[mint, maxt, dt]` in `DateList` format

The double-wrapped time specification is interpreted as the first 3 entries in calendar-date-format, and is expanded correctly, assuming 1 day-increment and automatically calculating the end-date from the number of data points:

```
TemporalData[Range@5, {{2001, 10, 2}}]["UnexpandedRawTimes"]

(* {TemporalData`DateSpecification[{2001, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0.},
                                   {2001, 10, 6, 0, 0, 0}, {1, "Day"}]} *)
```

Compare it with a single-wrapped time specification, that is interpreted as any iterator: "from 1 to 10 with steps of 2":

```
td = TemporalData[Range@5, {1, 10, 2}];
td["UnexpandedRawTimes"]

(* {{1, 10, 2}} *)

td["Times"]

(* {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}} *)
```

It uses the same argument specification `DateListPlot` accepts, where **$end$ and $start$ dates must comply with the $stepsize$ AND with the number of datapoints**, so a lot of naive combinations won't work (see further details under `ExtendTimes`). Increment by 1 week works, as the time span is 5 weeks, and there are exactly 5 datapoints:

```
DateList /@ 
  TemporalData[Range@5, {{2001, 1, 1}, {2001, 1, 29}, {1, "Week"}}]["Times"][[1]]

(* {{2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0.},
    {2001, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 1, 29, 0, 0, 0.}} *)
```

Increment by 2 days and `Automatic` endpoint (number of time divisions is defined by number of datapoints):

```
DateList /@ 
  TemporalData[Range@5, {{2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, Automatic, {2, "Day"}}]["Times"][[1]]

(* {{2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.},
    {2001, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0.}} *)
```

More detail is under [`DateListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateListPlot.html)'s specification, **Details and Options** section.

### DropTimes

`DropTimes` drops data points from a discrete time series. By default it works if time values are single numbers (e.g. `{1, 2, 3, ...}`). If time is specified in e.g. `DateList` format, it has to be converted to `AbsoluteTime` for `DropTimes`, as `TemporalData` automatically converts `DateList`-type date specifications to `AbsoluteTime`-format:

```
temp["Times"][[1, 1 ;; 5]]

(*  {3187296000, 3189974400, 3192393600, 3195072000, 3197664000} *)
```

By using `AbsoluteTime` on the time value to be removed, it works:

```
DateList /@ TemporalData`DropTimes[temp, AbsoluteTime@{2001, 2, 1}]["Times"][[1, ;; 5]]

(* {{2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0.},
    {2001, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0.}} *)
```

For comparison, below is the original 5 time values. Note that `{2002, 1, 1, ...}` is missing, and a new date is added at the end.

```
DateList /@ temp["Times"][[1, ;; 5]]

(* {{2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0.},
    {2001, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0.}} *)
```

### EnsembleApply

It allows one to do various kinds of arithmetic on time series without having to muck around with custom functions to avoid changing the dates.

> `EnsembleApply[f,td]` apply the function `f` to the state values of `td`.
>
> `EnsembleApply[f,td,lev]` apply `f` to the states at level `lev`.

```
DateListPlot[TemporalData`EnsembleApply[#1 + #1^2 &, temp]["Paths"],
  Joined -> True]
```

[image]

`EnsembleFold`, `EnsembleMap`, `EnsembleMapThread`, `EnsembleMovingMap` and `EnsembleTimeMap` work similarly.

> `EnsembleFold[f,td]` folds the function `f` over the state values in `td`.
>
> `EnsembleMap[f,td]` map the function `f` over the state values of `td`.
>
> `EnsembleMap[f,td,lev]` map `f` over the states at level `lev`.
>
> `EnsembleMapThread[f,td]` resamples by `"Union"` and creates a single path with states `{f[{s11,s21,...}],f[{s12,s22,...}],...}`.
>
> `EnsembleMovingMap[f,td,r]` computes running version of `f` over the states in `td` of order `r`.
>
> `EnsembleTimeMap[f,td]` maps the function `f` over the time stamps in `td`.

### ExtendTimes

This seems to work out what the $n$-th-next data point's time value would be, but it does it in `AbsoluteTime` space, which is not what you want for calendar data. As you can see, the last time period in my `fakedata` (or `temp` once converted to `TemporalData` form) is 1 April 2009, but three periods later is June 24, not July 1.

```
Map[DateList, (temp["Times"]), {2}][[1, -5 ;;]]
(* {{2008, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2009, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2009, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
  0.}, {2009, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2009, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0.}} *)

DateList[TemporalData`ExtendTimes[temp, 3][[1, 1]]]
(* {2009, 6, 24, 0, 0, 0.} *)
```

To extend times according to calendar dates, one has to specify calendar dates for `TemporalData` (implicit or explicit):

```
td = TemporalData[Range@5, {{2001, 1, 1}, {2001, 1, 29}, {1, "Week"}}];
td["UnexpandedRawTimes"]

(* {TemporalData`DateSpecification[{2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.},
                                   {2001, 1, 29, 0, 0, 0.}, {1, "Week"}]} *)

DateList /@ td["Times"][[1]]

(* {{2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0.},
    {2001, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 1, 29, 0, 0, 0.}} *)

TemporalData`ExtendTimes[td, 2]

(* {{{2001, 2, 12, 0, 0, 0.}}} (* two weeks are correctly added *)*)
```

### Resample

Resamples data according to the bin width specification.

> `Resample[td,t,f]` maps the function `f` over the state values and
>   resamples so that the paths have equivalent time stamps specified by `t`
>   where `t` can be `"Union"`, `"Intersection"`,a number, list of numbers, a
>   date increment such as `"Month"` or a list `{n,t}` where `n` is a number and
>   `t` is a date increment.
>
> `Resample[td,t]` is equivalent to `Resample[td,t,Identity]`
>
> `Resample[td]` is equivalent to `Resample[td,"Union"]`

Simulate a random walk for 200 steps and then resample it for bins of width 13:

```
td = Block[{i=0}, TemporalData[{#, i = i+RandomChoice@{-1, 1}} & /@ Range@200]];
new = TemporalData`Resample[td, 13];
new["Times"]

(* {{1, 14, 27, 40, 53, 66, 79, 92, 105, 118, 131, 144, 157, 170, 183, 196}} *)

{ListLinePlot@td, ListLinePlot@new}
```

[image]

With calendar dates, resample from 500 days to 2 months resolution:

```
td = TemporalData[{DatePlus[{2001, 1}, # - 1], #} & /@ Range@500];
DateList /@ TemporalData`Resample[td, {2, "Month"}]["Times"][[1]]

(* {{2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0.},
    {2001, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0.},
    {2002, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2002, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2002, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0.}} *)
```

### RescaleTimes

> `RescaleTimes[td,{tmin,tmax}]` rescales the paths to run from `tmin` to `tmax`.

If a single value is given instead of a pair, it is taken to be the new starting date, and the end date is shifted accordingly:

```
td = TemporalData[{#, #} & /@ Range@10];
td["Times"]

(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}} *)

TemporalData`RescaleTimes[td, 21]["Times"]

(* {{21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30}} *)

TemporalData`RescaleTimes[td, {101, 200}]["Times"]

(* {{101, 112, 123, 134, 145, 156, 167, 178, 189, 200}} *)
```

With calendar dates:

```
td = TemporalData[Range@4, {{2013, 10, 31}}];
DateList /@ First@td["Times"]

(* {{2013, 10, 31, 0, 0, 0.}, {2013, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0.},
    {2013, 11, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, {2013, 11, 3, 0, 0, 0.}} *)

new = TemporalData`RescaleTimes[td, {{1099, 12, 31}, {1110, 1, 5}}];
DateList /@ First@new["Times"]

(* {{1099, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0.}, {1103, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0.},
    {1106, 9, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, {1110, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}} *)

{DateListPlot@td@"Path", DateListPlot@new@"Path"}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### ShiftTimes

> `ShiftTimes[td,dt]` shifts the paths in `td` by `dt` units where `dt` can be a
>   number `t` or a date increment.

This one works the same way as `DatePlus`. Simulate a random walk starting at today, and then shift timestaps by 700 days:

```
td = TemporalData[NestList[RandomChoice@{-1, 1} + # &, 0, 100],
         {NestList[DatePlus[#, {1, "Month"}] &, {2013, 10, 31, 0, 0, 0}, 100]}];
new = TemporalData`ShiftTimes[td, {700, "Day"}];

{DateListPlot@td@"Path", DateListPlot@new@"Path"}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### TDListConvolve

> `TDListConvolve[ker,td]` performs a convolution on the state values in `td` using the kernel `ker`.

```
td = TemporalData[NestList[RandomChoice@{-1, 1} + # &, 0, 100], {Range@101}];
new = TemporalData`TDListConvolve[{.2, .3, .5}, td];
{ListLinePlot@td, ListLinePlot@new}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### TemporalDataInsert

> `TemporalDataInsert[td,{t,x},p]` inserts element `{t,x}` into `td` at path `p`
>   where `p` is specified as an integer, list of integers or `All`.

This adds the pair `{3, 11}` to the second path:

```
td = TemporalData[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 5, 10}}];
td["Paths"]

(* {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {5, 1}, {10, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {5, 2}, {10, 2}}} *)

new = TemporalData`TemporalDataInsert[td, {3, 11}, 2];
new["Paths"]

(* {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {5, 1}, {10, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 11}, {5, 2}, {10, 2}}} *)
```

Works with calendar dates as well.

### TemporalDataQ

> `TemporalDataQ[td]` test whether `td` is `TemporalData` and structurally valid.

```
TemporalData`TemporalDataQ[temp]
(* True *)    
TemporalData`TemporalDataQ[fakedata]
(* False *)
```

### TemporallyAlignedQ

> Returns `True` when all paths have same starting and ending times, othewise returns `False`.

```
TemporalData`TemporallyAlignedQ[{temp, templater}]
(* False *)
```

### TimeSeriesConcatenate

> `TimeSeriesConcatenate[td1, td2,...]` concatentates that paths of the `tdi`.

```
concated = TemporalData`TimeSeriesConcatenate[temp, templater];
DateListPlot[concated["Paths"], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

### UniformlySpacedQ

Again, as `TemporalData` converts `DateList`-format to seconds, `UniformlySpacedQ` might return `False` for data that is intuitively uniformly spaced, but not in the absolute sense, e.g. if time step size is given in `"Month"`:

```
TemporalData`UniformlySpacedQ@
   TemporalData[{DatePlus[{2001, 1}, {#, "Day"}], #} & /@ Range@10]

(* True *)

TemporalData`UniformlySpacedQ@
   TemporalData[{DatePlus[{2001, 1}, {#, "Month"}], #} & /@ Range@10]

(* False *)
```

### ValidTemporalDataQ

This does what you expect:

```
TemporalData`ValidTemporalDataQ[temp]
(* True *)
TemporalData`ValidTemporalDataQ[fakedata]
(* False *)
```

Comment: Extended it with details on `DropTimes`, `ExtendTimes`, `DateSpecification`.

Comment: Also cleared up the `"Month"` bug under `Aggregate`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar - nice, thanks! I hadn't had time to delve further into those bits.

Comment: It turns out that there are quite a few usage messages available, so I included them. I am still overwhelmed by the usefullness of what you have unearthed Verbeia, thanks!

Comment: @IstvánZachar - thanks for this! I suspect that this is the beginnings of some useful new functionality. We will have to wait and see if these functions are given more prominence in a future version.

Comment: Did you find a neat way to Rescale values of TemporalData? RescaleTimes obviously acts only on the times and not the values.

Comment: Verbeia, great response, very helpful and very interesting.  However I don't seem to be able to find the TemporalData` package in my Mathematica 9 installation.  Are you able to provide any pointers as to where I might find it?

Comment: OK, it appears the TemporalData` package is included automatically without the need to explicitly include it.