# How to partition a list into sublists in a similar way to Histogram

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have a list of list as below (I show part of it)

```
{{1902, 0.4662}, {1903, 0.22443}, {1905, 0.02936}, {1906, 
  0.02702}, {1908, -0.08354}, {1909, -0.05241}, {1911, 
  0.02388}, {1912, 0.03738}, {1914, 0.25015}, {1915, 0.2831}, {1917, 
  0.4415}, {1919, 0.18315}, {1921, 0.2256}, {1923, 0.24132}, {1926, 
  0.21473}, {1928, 0.29596}, {1930, 0.47693}, {1933, 0.41607}, {1935, 
  0.22161}, {1937, 0.3322}, {1940, 0.2099}, {1942, 0.23376}, {1944, 
  0.44114}, {1947, 0.15876}, {1949, 0.43953}, {1951, 0.71407}, {1954, 
  0.9595}, {1956, 0.59436}, {2000, 0.6832}, {2004, 0.86861}, {2007, 
  0.48201}, {2011, 0.70796}, {2015, 0.57029}, {2020, 0.61997}, {2026, 
  0.79266}, {2032, 0.78726}, {2038, 0.83884}}
```

For example, in {1902,0.4662} "1902" represent time 19:02 and 0.4662 represent the data at time 19:02.

**What I want to do is to calculate average of the data in every 5 minutes.** That is from 19:02 to 19:06, from 19:07 to 19:11. **Notice the time step is not evenly distributed.**

`Histogram` can naturally count how many of the data are in each interval. I want to partition the list like `Histogram` and then I can calculate average in each interval. 
And notice that the data may not be in a single day.

I can't figure out an elegant way to do this with built-in function. Can somebody help me?

Besides I think this is a very simple statistical calculation of data. **I want to know what software could do this easily and directly.**

Update:
the full data sample is here http://en.textsave.org/VdL with date information

Comment: You say that you want something from `19:07` to `19:11` but your set of data do not include `1907`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are your data always referring to the same day ?

Comment: @Öskå No, the data is not evenly distributed. Sometimes there is even no data within 5 minutes.

Comment: @b.gatessucks No, the instrument gathering the data all the time.

Comment: I think it's difficult to make something robust if you don't include the full date in your list.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I've add the full data here http://en.textsave.org/rdL

Comment: since you store the time as an integer you have to take care of the jumps from 2055 to 2100 etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach:

1. Create intervals from dataset;

   ```
   int = Table[Interval[{j, j + 4}], {j, 1902, 2038, 5}];
   ```
2. Calling your dataset `data` the means for the desired intervals can be obtained:

   ```
   Mean /@ GatherBy[data, IntervalMemberQ[int, #[[1]]] &][[All, All, 2]]
   ```

yielding:

> ```
> {0.186753, -0.0373567, 0.19021, 0.283417, 0.228025, 0.386445, 
> 0.31884, 0.27105, 0.33745, 0.437453, 0.77693, 0.6832, 0.86861, 
> 0.594985, 0.57029, 0.61997, 0.79266, 0.78726, 0.83884}
> ```

**EDIT**

Mr. Wizard correctly pointed out the error in my code. 
My first edit was wrong.
The easiest approach (it seems to me) is to convert times to temporal data.

```
f[x_] := {2013, 9, 28, IntegerPart[x/100], 
  100 (x/100 - IntegerPart[x/100])}
```

Then using `TemporalData`

```
td = TemporalData[{f[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ data];
answ = TemporalData`Aggregate[td, {5, "Minute"}]
```

The default function applied to the partitioned temporal data is mean.

This can be visualised:

```
DateListPlot[{td["Path"], answ["Path"]}, Joined -> {False, True}]
```

A good post is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30712/how-can-i-manipulate-temporaldata).

[image]

Comment: FYI: You need an extra four space indent under numbered lists for proper formatting.

Comment: You undid my edit.  I am guessing that was not intentional.  May I revert it?  Also, I see that your code can be simplified.  Do you mind if I edit it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was typing at same time and I am always happy to learn so feel free.

Comment: I have given my vote because this is an good idea.  However, it may not be complete as it does not account for a sixty minute hour.  I believe you will need to convert the data at some point to account for that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you. I agree that ideally the "time" could be managed better as a {y,m,d,h,m,s} and TemporalData has functionality.

Comment: @matheorem I agree that pre-processing dataset so that 'tied' time values can be dealt with should allow TemporalData`Aggregate[]. Otherwise using the methods based on partitioning into equivalence classes using a function on each element, e.g. Mr. Wizard, would work. My poor first approach was in this spirit.

Comment: @ubpdqn Thank you, ubpdqn! Your method using "TemporalData" is perfect in this problem. I made a mistake in my last reply. The second in `DataList` can be fractional number. So I can always add small varying quantity to the seconds to differentiate different data even in the same second.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably not going to be the fastest method as it doesn't make good use of vector optimizations, but I believe it is quite general and convenient.

```
split[data_, width_, normfn_] :=
  With[{offset = Mod[Min[normfn /@ First /@ data], width]},
    GatherBy[data, Floor[normfn[#[[1]]] - offset, width] &]
  ]
```

Now: with your data assigned to `data`:

```
dat2 = split[data, 5, QuotientRemainder[#, 100].{60, 1} &]
```

> ```
> {{{1902, 0.4662}, {1903, 0.22443}, {1905, 0.02936}, {1906, 0.02702}},
>  {{1908, -0.08354}, {1909, -0.05241}, {1911, 0.02388}}, ... }
> ```

`QuotientRemainder[#, 100].{60, 1} &` is an off-hand function to convert your hour-minute integers to minutes.

From there you can extract your second elements and find means:

```
Mean /@ data2[[All, All, 2]]
```

> ```
> {0.186753, -0.0373567, 0.19021, 0.283417, 0.228025, 0.386445, 0.31884, 0.27105,
>  0.33745, 0.437453, 0.77693, 0.6832, 0.86861, 0.594985, 0.57029, 0.61997, 0.79266, 
>  0.78726, 0.83884}
> ```

This function will not give values for empty bins.  It was not clear to me from the question if you want that.

---

Here is a different approach.  I will use `BinLists` this time which is I believe the intended function for such things, though at least in version 7 is often quite slow compared to alternatives (`GatherBy`) so I tend to avoid it.  It will however return empty bins which the method above does not.

This time I will convert the date/time data to single numeric values in advance and let `BinLists` do most of the rest.  For hour/minute data we may use:

```
normfn = QuotientRemainder[#, 100].{60, 1} &;
```

If your data includes dates you will need to split it differently and then use `AbsoluteTime`.  If you use `AbsoluteTime` the data will be in seconds rather than minutes so you will need to account for that.

```
data2 = data;
data2[[All, 1]] = normfn @ data2[[All, 1]];
{min, max} = {Min@#, Max@#} &[First /@ data2];

BinLists[data2, {min, max, 5}, {-1*^1000, 1*^1000, 2*^1000}]
```

You can process the data as needed from there.

Comment: My understanding is that same hour/minute but different date would be two different bins; does your function account for that (if you share my assumption) ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks The data only contains hour/minute per the OP's description.  If it is to include dates it will need a different format.  But that's a good point; really this should all be converted with `AbsoluteTime` for direct comparison.

Comment: By the way this code is far from my best; I'm applying `normfn` *twice* to every value for one thing.  However I'm just not in the mood to improve it right now.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you, Mr.Wizard! Your method using `Binlists` is quite general, I like it! It is hard to determine which answer should be accepted as the best answer. ubpdqn's answer using `TemporalData` is really suitable for this particular problem involving date.

Comment: @matheorem As stated I expect `GatherBy` to be more efficient (than `BinLists`) once the function is better written.  I'll try to do that soon but frankly I'm a bit fatigued with Stack Exchange at the moment and I'm working on other things.  As for Accepting, if all your data is date/time tagged I think `TemporalData` is the way to go (though I don't have it in v7 to compare; I'm assuming performance is good).  If/when I update `split` I'll be curios to know how it compares.

Comment: @matheorem I need some clarification from you: do you wish to partition the data preserving the pairs, e.g. `{{1902, 0.4662}, {1903, 0.22443}, {1905, 0.02936}, {1906, 0.02702}}` or is it sufficient to keep only the second values, e.g. `{0.4662, 0.22443, 0.02936, 0.02702}`?  Also, do you have anything against converting your time data to a different format?  In the first method I made sure to keep the output in exactly the same form as the input, only partitioned.  If that is not necessary I would write this differently.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The partition is good. I need to preserve the pairs. But I am afraid I need the empty bin to plot the 5 minutes average curve like `TemporalData` gives. Then how to get the empty bin? The method I can think of is to artificially insert zero data to those no data time region.

Comment: @matheorem Okay, noted that you need the pairs, and the empty bins too.  Do you need your data in the original format for any reason, or can the the first element of each pair be in another format such as produced by `AbsoluteTime`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah, it can be `AbsoluteTime`, and I can use`DateListPlot`. I reprocess my data, and now with date information. Herehttp://en.textsave.org/VdL

Answer (score 3):

### [TimeSeriesAggregate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesAggregate.html?q=TimeSeriesAggregate)

```
dl = MapAt[AbsoluteTime @ DateList[{StringInsert[ToString[#], ":", 3],
  {"Hour", "Minute"}}]&, data, {All, 1}];

dlmean = TimeSeriesAggregate[dl, {{5, "Minute"}, Left}, Mean];

DateListPlot[{dl, dlmean}, Joined -> {False, True}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
  GridLines -> {dlmean[[All, 1]], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let the list be `L`.

If the difference is 1 min all the time:

```
Mean /@ Partition[L[[All, 2]], 5]
```

If not, an approach could be:

```
Integrate[InterpolatingPolynomial[#, t], {t, -1/2, 9/2}]/5 & /@ 
  Map[{Mod[#[[1]], 5], #[[2]]} &, GatherBy[L, Quotient[#[[1]], 5] &], {2}]
```

Comment: I see, i added something now

Comment: Furthermore you can add back ticks `` when something is a variable such as `L`. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for more details.