# Scaling the output of TemporalData object

Tags: scaling, time-series

The RandomFunction generates an output in the form of TemporalData. How can I plot a scaled version of this data, e.g., all values divided by $n$ with time kept fixed? I read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30712/how-can-i-manipulate-temporaldata?rq=1) post but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: `s = RandomFunction[BinomialProcess[1/3], {0, 50}];
ListPlot[{s, s["PathStates"]/2}]`

Comment: @eldo's answer is better

Comment: With direct arithmetic on TemporalData in 10.3, normalization is not necessary: `s = RandomFunction[BinomialProcess[1/3], {10, 50}]; ListPlot[{s, s/2}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
td = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 1, .01}, 10];

ListLinePlot[td]
```

[image]

**Scaled**

```
ListLinePlot[Normal@td /. {a_, b_} :> {a, b/10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
td = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 1, .01}, 10];

GraphicsColumn[{ListLinePlot[td], ListLinePlot[td/10]}]
```

[image: Out]