# Using TemporalData`DropTimes

Tags: undocumented, time-series

I'm not able to figure out how the undocumented command `` TemporalData`DropTimes `` described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30712/how-can-i-manipulate-temporaldata) works.  For example, I have `TemporalData` like

```
temp = TemporalData[{{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}}]
```

and want to get rid of the last point, but

```
TemporalData`DropTimes[temp, 3]
```

doesn't do anything.  Anyone have any ideas, either using `DropTimes` or otherwise?

Comment: try ``temp = TemporalData`DropTimes[temp, 3]; temp``?

Comment: Do you need to trim events off of the start and end or delete events in the middle?

Comment: @kglr no, that doesn't work either

Comment: @Edmund, I'd like to remove the last event.

Comment: I must assume that this is because `TemporalData` reduces the time specification internally to an iterator of the form `{1, 3, 1}`. You can check it by `temp@"UnexpandedRawTimes"`. Nevertheless, I have no idea yet how to make it work.

Comment: Also it seems like that internals have been changed since v.9 because some examples in the link thread are not working anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `TimeSeriesWindow`.

```
TimeSeriesWindow[temp, {1, 2}]

(* TemporalData[Time: 1 to 2 Data points: 2 Paths: 1] *)
```

`TimeSeriesWindow` gives the events the fall between the window specified.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great, and even a documented command!